# How do I change the icon and text color?

Tags: fonts, icons, colors

Suddenly all of my icons and the text under the icons became grey in color.

I want the theme to be as it was when I first installed Ubuntu 11.10. The menu color was dark grey and icons were orange or red.

How do I reset my icon and color theme to default?

Answer (score 3):

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) and run following command(s) :

**Rebuilt Theme**

For Ambiance Theme:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme 'Ambiance'
```

For Radiance Theme:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme 'Radiance'
```

**Rebuilt icon package**:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme 'Unity-icon-theme'
```

Other default icon package:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme 'Ubuntu-mono-dark' 

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme 'Ubuntu-mono-light'
```

**Or reset Unity to default setting**:

```
unity --reset
```

Comment: Just to mention: `'Ubuntu-mono-dark'` has not the same effect that `'ubuntu-mono-dark'`, it is case sensitive. Using Ubuntu 13.04 I have different icons between those values.

Answer (score 0):

could you clarify, whether or not you did anything to the text or icon color before? or if it just happened out of thin air?

You could try these 2 things and see if it resets your icon theme defaults:

Go to System Settings -> Appearence and change the Theme (The default is Ambience)
If this doesn't help try this:

inside nautilus (the file manager) go to your home folder and hit ctrl-h to unhide all hidden folders. navigate to .config/dconf and change the name of the user file to user.old .

Log out and back in and see if the problem is fixed

Comment: Now suddenly came back to normal w/o touching anything, but thanks, if it happens again i will try what you suggested.

Comment: then it probably was some random graphics crash most likely compiz or gnome-settings-daemon related...most of the time loging out and back in (restarting display manager) fixes the problem.